# How handle ActionChains in Geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

i got autotests written in selenoum+python(all latest versions). For different actions on page i use actionschains, for example:

```
actions = ActionChains(self.browser)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
element.click()
```

in chrome/chromedriver on different version all passes, but when i run tests in firefox/geckodriver i got error:

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x106e62550>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"move target out of bounds","message":"(385, 1045) is out of bounds of vie...ys.mjs:472:23\\nreceiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:139:31\\n"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        """Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an
        error.
    
        :Args:
         - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
           object.
    
        :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
        """
        status = response.get("status", None)
        if not status or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return
        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen: str = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get("value", None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, str):
                import json
    
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    if len(value) == 1:
                        value = value["value"]
                    status = value.get("error", None)
                    if not status:
                        status = value.get("status", ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR)
                        message = value.get("value") or value.get("message")
                        if not isinstance(message, str):
                            value = message
                            message = message.get("message")
                    else:
                        message = value.get("message", None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
    
        exception_class: Type[WebDriverException]
        e = ErrorCode()
        error_codes = [item for item in dir(e) if not item.startswith("__")]
        for error_code in error_codes:
            error_info = getattr(ErrorCode, error_code)
            if isinstance(error_info, list) and status in error_info:
                exception_class = getattr(ExceptionMapping, error_code, WebDriverException)
                break
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
    
        if not value:
            value = response["value"]
        if isinstance(value, str):
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and "message" in value:
            message = value["message"]
    
        screen = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
        if "screen" in value:
            screen = value["screen"]
    
        stacktrace = None
        st_value = value.get("stackTrace") or value.get("stacktrace")
        if st_value:
            if isinstance(st_value, str):
                stacktrace = st_value.split("\n")
            else:
                stacktrace = []
                try:
                    for frame in st_value:
                        line = frame.get("lineNumber", "")
                        file = frame.get("fileName", "<anonymous>")
                        if line:
                            file = f"{file}:{line}"
                        meth = frame.get("methodName", "<anonymous>")
                        if "className" in frame:
                            meth = f"{frame['className']}.{meth}"
                        msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                        msg = msg % (meth, file)
                        stacktrace.append(msg)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
        if exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            alert_text = None
            if "data" in value:
                alert_text = value["data"].get("text")
            elif "alert" in value:
                alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (385, 1045) is out of bounds of viewport width (1920) and height (970)
E       Stacktrace:
E       RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
E       WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5
E       MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:370:5
E       assertInViewPort@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.sys.mjs:2113:11
E       dispatch@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.sys.mjs:1011:21
E       dispatch/pendingEvents<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.sys.mjs:1827:14
E       dispatch@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.sys.mjs:1826:39
E       dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.sys.mjs:1753:27
E       dispatch@chrome://remote/content/marionette/action.sys.mjs:1755:7
E       performActions@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:472:23
E       receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:139:31

venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:229: MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
```

so geckodriver doesn't use actionschains and all my tests failed. There any fix for that, except use javascript commands?

I tried different versions of firefox, but still got this problem.

Comment: I have been trying to scroll my viewport so that an element is clickable. However, of the three methods I've tested only one works. 1) Scrolling using expected_condition with a failed, 2) Scrolling with action_chains `move_to_element()`, `scroll_to_element()`, and `scroll_by_amount()` all failed, 3) Using `execute_script()` to run Javascript was the only success case.